# What is to do next in this ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

After many research, I deduced I need to use an AJAX request if I want to transit javascript variables to a php function. I've read a tutorial on it, and I think I've well started. However, I don't know what I have to do next: if someone could explain me the process to which I am (as it is a little nebulous), it would be very appreciated! Here's what I did:

```
// encode the variables
dayInput = encodeURIComponent(dayInput);
monthInput = encodeURIComponent(monthInput);
yearInput = encodeURIComponent(yearInput);

// prepare the ajax request
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'createList.php?day=' + dayInput + '&month=' + monthInput + '&year=' + yearInput);
xhr.send(NULL);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE && xhr.status == 200)
    {
        //WHAT TO DO??
    }
}
```

Comment: You do whatever you want to do with the results that the script sends back. Usually this means inserting things into the DOM so they get displayed to the user.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that none of the AJAX tutorials you looked at include examples of this.

Comment: On the other hand, I applaud you for using `encodeURIComponent`. Most examples forget about this detail.

Comment: But what happens when the last if condition is met? If I want to use the variables per say and use them in php in createList.php, can I call them? I'm not sure to fully understand what this whole request has really done...

Comment: You've sent a request to the server, and the script runs. The `if` condition indicates that you received the response back from the server. You can then get the response from `xhr.responseText`.

Comment: I'm still totally not believing that the tutorials leave this out.

Comment: Yeah, I've read about the xhr.responseText. But, is this response usable by the php?

Comment: The PHP script can use `$_GET['day']`, etc. to get the parameters. It should echo the result, and that's what will be in `xhr.responseText`. If it sends back HTML, you can put that in `document.getElementById('someID').innerHTML`

Comment: What do you mean "usable by the php"? The response is sent **from** the PHP, and Javascript uses it.

Comment: Ok, so I can do I can call $_GET. Thanks a lot, I needed more explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the script sends HTML back, you can insert it into the DOM like this:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE && xhr.status == 200){
        document.getElementById('listbox').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
}
```

Comment: If my php echoes a list of <li>, could I do this into the if condition?

document.getElementsByTagName('ul').appendChild(xhr.responseText);

Comment: No, you can't. The argument to `appendChild` is a DOM element, not HTML code. You can use `document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].innerHTML += xhr.responseText`.

Comment: This is all just basic DOM manipulation, which any Javascript programmer should be familiar with. It doesn't change just because the data came from AJAX.

Comment: Thanks! My experience is very little in javascript, and even less in ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with the data returned by the php page, you should **parse it** into a DOM element so it will be accessible with JavaScript:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE && xhr.status == 200){
        var parser = new DOMparser(),
            doc = parser.parse(xhr.responseText, 'text/html');

        // do something with doc, like:
        var list = doc.getElementById('list');
        document.getElementById('some-id').innerHTML = list;
    }
}
```